# Match 'n' occurance of special character in a column in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table in postgres with following columns

```
col1           col2
1              A11CC | D05AX
2              N06AX | N07BA
3              D01AC | G01AG | J02AC | S01AX
4              null
```

My aim is to fetch those rows where there is single occurance of '|'. I tried following query but it not giving me the desired output.

```
select *, regexp_match(col2, '.*\|{1}') from table;
```

The desired output is:

```
col1           col2
1              A11CC | D05AX
2              N06AX | N07BA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
select *, regexp_matches(col2, '^[^\|]*\|[^\|]*$') from table;
```

The problem in your regex is that `.*` means "any char 0 or more times", and `|` match "any char". Check [this article](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/why-using-the-greedy-in-regular-expressions-is-almost-never-what-you-actually-want) for more information about the use of `.*`.

I modified the regex to be sure that the other chars are not `|` using `[^\|]`.

Comment: This works.. How can I exclude other rows where there is no '|' or more than 1 occurance of '|' in the output?

Comment: @rshar answer edited, try this. The error was the `regexp_match` instead of `regexp_matches`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a expression which discards all characters other than "|", then take the length of the resulting string. So:

```
with test_set( col1, col2) as 
     ( values (1,'A11CC | D05AX')
            , (2,'N06AX | N07BA')
            , (3,'D01AC | G01AG | J02AC | S01AX')
            , (4,null)
     )          
select ts.*    
  from test_set ts
 where length(regexp_replace(ts.col2,'[^|]','','g')) = 1;
```